# How to setEnabled() in javafx-8?

Tags: javafx-8

Unlike Swing Javafx-8 doesn't appear to have "setEnabled()" methods (or equivalent) for UI controls. Suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: Thanks Dyrandz, I'll look up the object hierarchy more carefully next time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setDisable()` instead of setEnabled() in javaFx.. 
like `button.setDisable(false)`

`setDisable` is a public method for disabling a node, `setDisabled` is a protected method used only by internal implementations